# Mechanics of a GWTP servlet

Tags: java, servlets, gwtp

I've snooped around the internet without finding anything that truly seems to satisfy me on this one.

I'd like to know what the mechanics are behind the execution of a servlet in a GWTP environment, and maybe a comparison with how a "usual" servlet runs.

Allow me to define more clearly where I'm coming from : in a GWT project, it is mandatory that servlets use the @Singleton annotation. What I want to know is what that implies once people start sending requests to the servlet. Are the requests handled one at a time? What happens once an important amount of people start trying to connect at the same time? Are there things that I specifically want to avoid doing in my servlet to avoid conflicts?

Thank you in advance for helping to clarify this or pointing me to ressources that explain this clearly.

Comment: Do you mean the internal workings of the GWTP servlets that run the command pattern, or creating your own servlets? One of the benefits of using GWTP over vanilla GWT is the command pattern: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/RPC-Dispatch. You can also write your own servlets as well but they will simply be regular GWT code.

Comment: I guess I'd like to know for GWTP actions (called using the DispatchAsync method) as well as for servlets (which are accessed by doing a form submission client side to the server, and are dispatched server-side with the lines `serve("/" + ActionImpl.DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME + "*").with(DispatchServiceImpl.class);
  serve("/imageToBD").with(ImageToBD.class);`